# Upgrade to Mysql 8 or MariaDB 10.3 for InnoDB Fulltext searches?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, full-text-search

I'm upgrading a Mysql 5.7 server and have the choice to move to Mysql 8 or MariaDB 10.3.

The by far most important function in this database server is InnoDB fulltext search which I haven't found compared in the usual Mysql vs MariaDB comparisons.

What are the pros and cons of each? Does one of them have an edge in fulltext searching?

What about even newer versions of each?

Comment: What are you after from a full text search? I'm suspecting you'd get a better functionality from a dedicated full text search database rather than a database with the limited functionality added on in a way that MySQL and MariaDB do.

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect either to have an 'edge'.

5.6 and 10.0(?) had the same InnoDB FULLTEXT; they have not diverged much since then (with respect to FULLTEXT).

If you switch to MariaDB, you may as well go to 10.5.

Will you be using non-English text and searches?  If so there may be issues.

Comment: I tried both versions available directly in Ubuntu 20.04, Mysql 8 and MariaDB 10.3. Mysql 8 worked similar to 5.7, but MariaDB 10.3 kept crashing. I moved to MariaDB 10.6 now and it works fine.

Comment: @GeneVincent - Interesting.  Can you further describe how 10.3 crashed?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3 kept hitting an assert() in the InnoDB code when searching in the fulltext index. This is a rather large database with ~350 million entries and I found similar bug reports when googeling. But with 10.6 it seems to be fine, I didn't try versions in between.